# What does (A) in patent number US744484(A) denote?

Tags: filing

I also seen (C) in some, what do they denote? What can I learn about a patent or application based on its alpha-suffix?

Answer (score 1):

How curious that you're interested in a [corset, patented in 1903](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/US_744484_A)!  The 'A' is called a 'Kind Code' and is different for different jurisdictions, and also differs over time in some jurisdictions (e.g. before 2001, an 'A' kind code in the USA meant a granted patent; after that time it meant a Patent Application). Here's a [useful table of USPTO Kind Codes](http://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/patent-search/authority-files/uspto-kind-codes).  FYI, it is a real headache for integrated patent system analysis and requires lots of 'binning' to get equivalent types of documents/rights to be displayed.